# SQL How to replace values of select return?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In my database table (MySQL), there is a column with `1` and `0` to represent `true` and `false` respectively.

But in `SELECT`, I need to replace it for `true` or `false` in order to print in a GridView.

How do I make my `SELECT` query to do this?

In my current table:

```
 id   |  name    |  hide
  1   |  Paul    |  1
  2   |  John    |  0
  3   |  Jessica |  1
```

I need it to show thereby:

```
  id  |  name    |  hide
  1   |  Paul    |  true
  2   |  John    |  false
  3   |  Jessica |  true
```

Comment: Please remember that tables have names — we can invent names for you, but it gives the answers greater consistency if you tell us the name of the table.  It is also a good idea to specify which DBMS you're using since there are variations between the different DBMS.

Comment: Thank you! I will remember this the next!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You have a number of choices:

1. Join with a domain table with `TRUE`, `FALSE` *Boolean* value.
2. Use ([as pointed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753165/2308745))

   ```
   SELECT CASE WHEN hide = 0 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END FROM
   ```

   Or if *Boolean* is not supported:

   ```
   SELECT CASE WHEN hide = 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END FROM
   ```

Answer (score 54):

I got the solution

```
   SELECT 
   CASE status
      WHEN 'VS' THEN 'validated by subsidiary'
      WHEN 'NA' THEN 'not acceptable'
      WHEN 'D'  THEN 'delisted'
      ELSE 'validated'
   END AS STATUS
   FROM SUPP_STATUS
```

This is using the CASE
This is another to manipulate the selected value for more that two options.

Answer (score 34):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT id,name, REPLACE(REPLACE(hide,0,"false"),1,"true") AS hide FROM your-table
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: While it works given the REPLACE function (which DBMS has that?), the double application is not all that elegant, and doesn't extend to 3 or more cases very well, does it?  It is an alternative answer, though.

Comment: I just tried it with MySQL and you are right is not very good approach if you have more than 3 cases, but in this case this solution works as you mention. :) thanks for commenting

Comment: I actually like this approach for a 2 different values and it's a bit easier to look at in the select statement than CASE/WHEN block.

Comment: While this works, it's a hack.  Replace is a string substitution facility.  Suppose something changes and the string "01" comes through instead of 1.  This will be converted to "falsetrue".  It's better to have some explicit matching of the whole variable.

Answer (score 25):

If you want the column as string values, then:

```
SELECT id, name, CASE WHEN hide = 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS hide
  FROM anonymous_table
```

If the DBMS supports BOOLEAN, you can use instead:

```
SELECT id, name, CASE WHEN hide = 0 THEN false ELSE true END AS hide
  FROM anonymous_table
```

That's the same except that the quotes around the names `false` and `true` were removed.

Comment: Mysql 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - To get `As hide` to work, I had to put parentheses around `CASE ... END`.  So:  `SELECT id, name, (CASE WHEN ... END) AS hide FROM ...`

Answer (score 8):

You can use casting in the select clause like:

```
SELECT id, name, CAST(hide AS BOOLEAN) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

I saying that the case statement is wrong but this can be a good solution instead.
If you choose to use the `CASE` statement, you have to make sure that at least one of the `CASE` condition is matched. Otherwise, you need to define an error handler to catch the error. Recall that you don’t have to do this with the `IF` statement.

```
SELECT if(hide = 0,FALSE,TRUE) col FROM tbl; #for BOOLEAN Value return
```

or

```
SELECT if(hide = 0,'FALSE','TRUE') col FROM tbl; #for string Value return
```

Answer (score 0):

in Postgres 11 I had to do this:

`type` is an `int`

```sql
SELECT type,
CASE 
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'todo'
    ELSE 'event'
END as type_s
from calendar_items;
```

Answer (score -2):

*replace the value in select statement itself*

```
(CASE WHEN Mobile LIKE '966%' THEN (select REPLACE(CAST(Mobile AS nvarchar(MAX)),'966','0')) ELSE Mobile END)
```

Comment: You have to tell the reason why your answer will work !